# Parsing for JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have made an API call to a service that returns JSON data. If I log the data using: JSON.parse(response.body);

This gets logged:

```
{ Results: 
   [ { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2016-03-25T21:28:22Z',
       MonitorType: 0,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId01',
       Status: 0 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2016-03-25T21:30:15Z',
       MonitorType: 1,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId01',
       Status: 0 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2016-03-25T21:30:15Z',
       MonitorType: 2,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId01',
       Status: 0 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2016-03-25T21:28:49Z',
       MonitorType: 0,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId02',
       Status: 0 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2016-03-25T21:35:23Z',
       MonitorType: 1,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId02',
       Status: 0 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2016-03-25T21:35:23Z',
       MonitorType: 2,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId02',
       Status: 0 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2014-11-03T16:20:15Z',
       MonitorType: 0,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId03',
       Status: 2 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: true,
       LastOccurrence: '2013-08-30T21:44:41Z',
       MonitorType: 0,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId04',
       Status: 2 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: false,
       LastOccurrence: '2014-11-03T16:34:45Z',
       MonitorType: 1,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId03',
       Status: 1 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: false,
       LastOccurrence: '2014-11-03T16:34:45Z',
       MonitorType: 2,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId03',
       Status: 1 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: false,
       LastOccurrence: '2013-08-30T21:57:58Z',
       MonitorType: 1,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId04',
       Status: 1 },
     { Interval: 900,
       IsNodeActive: false,
       LastOccurrence: '2013-08-30T21:57:58Z',
       MonitorType: 2,
       NodeName: 'fmsHealthMonitorAppId04',
       Status: 1 } ] }
```

Then if I do:

```
var resp = JSON.parse(response.body);
var totalStatuses = Object.keys(resp.Results).length;
```

`totalStatuses` contains 12 the correct count.

Now I want to loop through each section of the data and examine the value of LastOccurrence. This is eluding me. What would the correct syntax be to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother using `Object.keys`, that's only if you want to get the keys of an object. What you have there is an array. With that, you can iterate through it using a simple `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < resp.Results.length; i++) {
  var result = resp.Results[i];
  console.log(result.LastOccurrence);
}
```

Comment: Perfect Mike! One follow on. I need to turn result.LastOccurrence into milliseconds by calling Date.parse() on it. I tried:

var last_time = Date.parse(result.LastOccurrence); or adding toString() to the end but those both gave a TypeError saying undefined is not a function. What would be the way to do this?

Comment: @Bob `Date.parse` will convert it into milliseconds for you. `Date.parse('2016-03-25T21:28:22Z') === 1458941302000`. Alternatively, you can create a `Date` object then use `getTime`. `new Date(result.LastOccurrence).getTime()`.

Answer (score 0):

This have to work

```
for(var i = 0; i < totalStatuses ; i += 1){ 
    var obj = resp[i];
    console.log(obj.LastOccurrence);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`resp.Results` is an array of objects, but `Object.keys` function expects its argument to be an object. 
To iterate through `resp.Results` array:

```
var results = resp.Results, len = resp.Results.length;
while (len--) {
    console.log(result[len].LastOccurrence);
}
```